# Signatures for trends of variable movement

Tags: algorithm, data-analysis

Can someone point me in the direction of algorithms I should study to solve the following task:

I have about 10 variables. They constantly change, I record their changes. I need to find different places in the data where the movement of the variables is similar: in both places x1 goes up 50%, x2 goes down 20%, x3 stays in place, and so on for all 10. Say this happens at time point 15 and again at time point 225. I need to recognize that pattern, therefore I need to produce a "signature" for each general category of such a sum of movements.

Optimally, this signature should extended to reasonably long rows: x1 up 15%, down 20%, up 30%, but always for all 10 variables together. In finance they probably need to do this for stock analysis, but what algorithms do they employ?

EDIT: I'm looking into the multidimensional trees in the first answer, but now I'm also considering an alternative path: since the values have to add up to a hundred, and I can be increasingly approximate with higher values (anything over 50% just scores as "over half", for example), then I can use the fact that the higher "shelves" can only be occupied by a very limited number of the variables (only one "over half", only 3 in "30-50%" category, etc) to reduce the total amount of possible variations for each recorded distribution. I could construct a hash function to give a key for each distribution and then include with it the keys for each distribution that follows the original distribution.

Comment: Any limitations? What's the scale of the data? A brute force solution can solve it in `O(n)` per 'new' entry recieved (or `O(n^2)` total).

Comment: The values of the variables are percentages, their sum is always 100%. The data rows can reach 100 000 in length. There is some leeway in precision, the variables can be put in "shelves": say, from 1 to 2%, from 2 to 5%. I need to count the most frequent patterns of the variables moving from one "shelf" to another.

Comment: If your data are percentages X1,X2...XD there are connections and constraints between this. For some analysis it is good to replace them with log(X1/XD), log(X2/XD)... log(X{D-1}/XD) - see http://www.leg.ufpr.br/lib/exe/fetch.php/pessoais:abtmartins:a_concise_guide_to_compositional_data_analysis.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the very interesting link. But from what I understand, these methods produce something like a measure of "atypicality" - I don't need this, because I don't have a typical case and cases that measure a similar high value of atypicality can actually have a wildly different composition. The paper also doesn't seem to mention anything similar to my "shelves", predetermined levels of similarity. But this does seem to be the correct field, so I'll explore it further.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [k-d tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree), with 10-dimensions, 1 for each variable.

Once you receive a 'change':

1. Check the tree for the nearest neighbor of the new change. Verify if it is 'close enough' to consider as similar, and if so - output it.
2. Insert the new change to the tree, so the future changes can access it.

Since nearest neighbor search and insertions are both `O(logN)` in k-d tree, each change requires `O(logN)` to check, and the total is `O(NlogN)`.

Comment: Would this also allow me to compare sequences of changes? A pattern might not become clear until the variables have changed 4 or 5 times.

Comment: @user3101050 Sure, have an additional [disjoint set DS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure), and maintain a set for every 'similar' group of changes. When you are done, each set represent a group of similar changes.